# React JS: How to send value of button to textbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Button:

```
<button className="name" id="michael" value="Michael Smith" onClick="">Michael Smith <small className="small">Senior Loan Officer</small></button>
```

TextBox:

```
<input type="text" className="textbox" value="" placeholder="Select who you would like to book with" />
```

Want to send the button value to the textbox using react. How to do?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  In order for us to help you, we need to see some of your own code.

Answer (score 0):

To do so you bind them both to the same value, presumably stored in the state of the component that renders them both:

```
<button className="name" id="michael" value={this.state.userName} onClick="">Michael Smith <small className="small">Senior Loan Officer</small></button>

<input type="text" className="textbox" value={this.state.userName} placeholder="Select who you would like to book with" />
```

In react you should get away from thinking in terms of sending values from one componetn to another when action occurs. Instead you update your state and that triggers re-rendering of the components.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle button click in your button element through a handler and a call to setState, and in your input link the value to the state attribute. If the input is editable, you'll have to handle the changes using the onChange callback to update the state.

Something like this:

```
<button className="name" id="michael" value="Michael Smith" onClick={()=>this.setState({selectedValue:"Michael Smith"})>Michael Smith <small className="small">Senior Loan Officer</small></button>

<input type="text" className="textbox" value={this.state.selectedValue} onChange={(e)=>this.setState({selectedValue:e.target.value})} placeholder="Select who you would like to book with" />
```